# How can I update binary data in database

Tags: c#, database

I want to make update query which will update all data in textbox, combobox and picture box. When I created query for Textbox and combobox, it's working fine. but when I add picturebox image binary data, somehow query stopped working and it's also not showing any error, it just not updating data. I want to update all data in database

Here the code

```
private void updatebill()
{
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cn.Open();
        }

        da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        dt = new DataTable();
        ds = new DataSet();

        string str;

        str = "UPDATE BillTable set [Bill_No]= '"+ billno.Text + "', [Bill_Year] = '" + fylabel.Text + "', [Group_ID]= '" + groupidDB + "', [Vendor_Id]= '" + vendoridDB + "', [Amount]= '" + amount.Text + "', Picture1= @pict1 , Picture2= @pict2, Picture3= @pict3, Picture4= @pict4  where (ID= @billID)";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billID", Convert.ToString(BillIdentity.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voucher", Convert.ToString(voucher.Text));

        // picture box
        if (PictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image);
            byte[] pic = ImageToBytes(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict1", pic);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict1", OleDbType.Binary).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        if (pictureBox2.Image != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
            byte[] pic2 = ImageToBytes(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict2", pic2);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict2", OleDbType.Binary).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        if (pictureBox3.Image != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox3.Image);
            byte[] pic3 = ImageToBytes(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict3", pic3);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict3", OleDbType.Binary).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        if (pictureBox4.Image != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox4.Image);
            byte[] pic4 = ImageToBytes(bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict4", pic4);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pict4", OleDbType.Binary).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
}

private byte[] ImageToBytes(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream menStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(menStream, format);
            return menStream.ToArray();
        }
}
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What type of `Picture1` column? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: As an aside, why are you randomly parameterising only half the input values in the SQL? You need to parameterise everything for it to be properly secure and less vulnerable to syntax issues.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I am using MS access and data type of Picture1 is OLE Object

Comment: @ADyson Initally i parameterised all the input but when I encountered this problem, I randomly trying few change in the code just to know where's the error. By doing so I removed parameterised value of textbox and combobox input.

Comment: Your other inputs are unlikely to be the source of the problem, if they worked before. And un-parameterising is only likely to introduce more problems, instead of reducing them.

Comment: Are you really certain this throws no errors? It's very unusual for the query to simply do _nothing_. The only reason for that to happen, in an UPDATE query, might be if there are no rows which match the provided `billID` value - if so it'll "succeed" (i.e. not crash) but also not find any rows to update. But simply adding pictures into the code shouldn't affect that - did you change anything else at the same time? Also, you haven't wrapped the call to your function inside a try/catch block which is hiding exceptions, by any chance?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for suggestion i will surely add these parameters back, As I am very new to coding I didn't know that even it would create new problem. And yes I am sure that it's not throwing any error and also not updating the database. Also I didn't add these function inside try/catch block.

Comment: "I am sure that it's not throwing any error and also not updating the database" ...well then please use your debugger to check whether the Bill ID you're entering actually matches any rows in the database. Based on the information you've provided and the assertions you've made, that seems to be the most likely reason for the issue.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks Buddy. By your suggestion i rewrite entire parameters and now my update query is working properly. There was mistake in sequence of paramters.